# nth-child pseudo selector within bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 columns and I want each one of them to have a different border color without adding a specific class to each one.

So, I'm thinking to use `:nth-child` to make this work.
Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dynamyc/9da2G/)

I have this markup:

```
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">


          <div class="col-lg-6 flush-col">

          <div class="thumbnail">


          <h3>DUMMY CONTENT</h3>

         </div>

          </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 flush-col">

          <div class="thumbnail">



          <h3>DUMMY CONTENT</h3>

         </div>

          </div>
        </div>  



        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-6 flush-col">

          <div class="thumbnail">


          <h3>DUMMY CONTENT</h3>

         </div>

          </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 flush-col">

          <div class="thumbnail">


          <h3>DUMMY CONTENT</h3>

         </div>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

Here is the css: `.thumbnail:nth-child(1) {border:1px solid red;}`

But this is changing all the columns not just the one I expect to be changed.
How can I make this work?

Comment: So which ones do you want to change...it's not clear from your question. In the CSS you have already posted the `.thumbnail:nth-child(1)` will select **every** `.thumbnail` div because they are all `:first-child`.

Comment: I want to be able to change each `.thumbnail` to have different border color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use :nth-child at this point because .thumbnail is always the first child:

You have 2 rows, so you can use first-child and last-child inside each row like this:

```
.container .row:first-child .flush-col:first-child .thumnail {border:1px solid red;}
.container .row:first-child .flush-col:last-child .thumnail {border:1px solid blue;}
.container .row:last-child .flush-col:first-child .thumnail {border:1px solid black;}
.container .row:last-child .flush-col:last-child .thumnail {border:1px solid yellow;}
```

or with :nth-child

```
.container .row:nth-child(1) .flush-col:nth-child(1) .thumnail {border:1px solid red;}
.container .row:nth-child(1) .flush-col:nth-child(2) .thumnail {border:1px solid blue;}
.container .row:nth-child(2) .flush-col:nth-child(1) .thumnail {border:1px solid black;}
.container .row:nth-child(2) .flush-col:nth-child(2) .thumnail {border:1px solid yellow;}
```